# How about reduce recursion times by detecting border situations in advance

Tags: python, algorithm

For example, the code in textbook -- solving Fibonacci problem by using recursion -- is like this:

```
cache = {}

def fibo(n):
    if n in cache :
        return cache[n]
    elif n <=2:
        cache[n] = 1
    else:
        cache[n] = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
    return cache[n]
```

However, i am concerned every time doing function calls, costs are needed. Why didn't the textbook use this code instead, to avoid unnecessary function call:

```
cache = {}

def fibo(n):
    if n <=2:
        cache[n] = 1
    else:
        # to avoid unnecessary function call
        if n-1 in cache:
            f1 = cache[n-1]
        else:
            f1 = fibo(n-1)
        if n-2 in cache:
            f2 = cache[n-2]
        else:
            f2 = fibo(n-2)

        cache[n] = f1 + f2

    return cache[n]
```

In this way, we could avoid unnecessary function call before actually calling it.

Anyway, my question is, why don't the authors of the textbook write the code in the second way?

Comment: You do realize that you are not using `f1` and `f2`, so you are making more unnecessary function calls, right?

Comment: I'd say generally they're trying to show a single concept - usually recursion.  Optimizing the recursive function can come later.

Comment: Because code samples should favor readability over (premature) microoptimizations. That's the same reason they didn't replace the global lookups with local variables.

Comment: One alternative approach would be use a better caching method, such as [_probably the fastest memoization decorator in the world_](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/?in=lang-python) and just simplifying your function by removing all the embedded code for caching.

Comment: @murgatroid99 sorry it's a code typo :( i've fixed it. but i guess you got what i tried to say.

Comment: I will point out that your proposed code (with the fix) saves about 3 function calls over the original code, and if the current value is already in the array it makes a couple of *extra* array accesses. Basically, it's a micro-optimization that's not worth the hit in readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). You're using an array to store the steps of recursion, ala [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). For something like Fibonacci, where there is more than one recursive call per iteration, dynamic programming is indeed the preferred technique.

As for why the textbook showed you the code it did, most likely because the authors wanted to just demonstrate recursion without going into too many concepts at once.